# What are the benefits of Sketch for PSTricks users?

Tags: pstricks

When it comes to graphics and TeX I tent to be PostScript biased in part 
due to my age (TikZ didn't exist when I started learning TeX). 
Recently, I learned about [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/). I was wondering what are the benefits of
learning Sketch for the casual PSTricks user if any? Is there something which
is trivial to do with Sketch but not so easy using PSTricks and its extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if someone starts new with creating graphics then it make sense to use sketch, but if you are familiar with PSTricks there will be no benefit.

And, of course, the exported PSTricks code which is exported from within Sketch is often lousy and difficult to modify, if needed.